# When using ruamel.yaml and preserve_quotes=True is there a way to force roundtriped yaml to use single quotes?

Tags: ruamel.yaml

[Updated question, `preserve_quotes` works as expected]

How can I force the output to use single quotes whatever the type quotes used in the input, but only if quotes were used?

Note : the (humble) source code of my projects using ruamel.yaml =>

- https://github.com/looztra/yamkix (an opinionated yaml formatter)
- https://github.com/looztra/kubesplit/tree/v0_scooter (a tool designed to split a set of kubernetes resources in a single stream to a set of files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example output has the single quotes changed, i.e. not preserved
and a minimal example shows that is not how things work.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """---
metadata:
  annotations:
    first: '1'
    second: any string
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
data = list(yaml.load_all(yaml_str))
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.explicit_start = True
yaml.dump_all(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
---
metadata:
  annotations:
    first: '1'
    second: any string
```

Using your `format_yaml` routine:

```
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml
YAML = ruamel.yaml.YAML

yaml_file = pathlib.Path("temp.yaml")
yaml_file.write_text("""---
metadata:
  annotations:
    first: '1'
    second: any string
""")


def format_yaml(input_file,
                output_file,
                explicit_start=True,
                explicit_end=False,
                default_flow_style=False,
                dash_inwards=True,
                quotes_preserved=True,
                parsing_mode='rt'):
    """
    Load a file and save it formated :
    :param input_file: the input file
    :param output_file: the output file
    :param explicit_start: write the start of the yaml doc even when there is \
                            only one done in the file
    :param default_flow_style: if False, block style will be used for nested \
                              arrays/maps
    :param dash_inwards: push dash inwards if True
    :param quotes_preserved: preserve quotes if True
    :param parsing_typ: safe or roundtrip (rt) more
    """
    yaml = YAML(typ=parsing_mode)
    yaml.explicit_start = explicit_start
    yaml.explicit_end = explicit_end
    yaml.default_flow_style = default_flow_style
    yaml.preserve_quotes = quotes_preserved
    if dash_inwards:
        yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)

    if input_file is not None:
        with open(input_file, 'rt') as f_input:
            parsed = yaml.load_all(f_input.read())
    else:
        parsed = yaml.load_all(sys.stdin.read())
    ready_for_dump = []
    try:
        # Read the parsed content to force the scanner to issue errors if any
        for data in parsed:
            ready_for_dump.append(data)
    except ScannerError as e:
        print("Something is wrong in the input file, got error from Scanner")
        print(e)
        return
    if output_file is not None:
        with open(output_file, 'wt') as out:
            yaml.dump_all(ready_for_dump, out)
    else:
        yaml.dump_all(ready_for_dump, sys.stdout)

format_yaml(yaml_file, None)
```

which also gives:

```
---
metadata:
  annotations:
    first: '1'
    second: any string
```

and if you use double quotes in the input, you'll get double quotes in the output.
So please provide is with a **minimal** full example program that shows the behaviour 
that you get, plus the ruamel.yaml and python versions and the platforms you have tested this on (the above was tested with 0.15.97 on Python 3.7.3 and Python 2.7.15 (with `pathlib2` installed) on Linux).

---

BTW, the easiest way of changing all single quoted string to dump as double quoted ones
in round-trip mode is by overriding the `represent_single_quoted_scalarstring` method
on `yaml.representer` (e.g by assigning the `represent_double_quoted_scalarstring` method to it).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and please accept my apologies, it actually works as expected. I have been tricked by one of the tools (kustomize) in my real life usecase. Kustomize is the tool in the chain that was converting single quotes to double quotes, and that is not coming from ruamel.yaml. By the way, thank you for the `represent_single_quoted_scalarstring` tip.